# "A Better Camera Unlocked" question

Tags: applications

I'm using a Galaxy S5 Android with version 6.0.1. I like the app called "A Better Camera Unlocked" but it is baffling me because sometimes it saves photos to the internal storage of the phone and sometimes to the micro-SD card, which is where I want them ALL saved. Any idea how to get it to save ONLY to the SD card? TIA for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this app，It can set the file save path，in the main activity，click the arrow ，and than click more settings--save&share，now you can set it。